# Play framework подождать выполнение нескольких задач (CompletableFuture.allOf)

Tags: java, playframework

Разбираюсь с фреймворком play. Необходимо сделать несколько запросов в БД, и по результатам их выполнения сделать бизнес логику.

Слой Repository возвращает CompletionStage

```
    public CompletionStage<Account> get(Long id) {
        return supplyAsync(() -> wrap(em -> Failsafe.with(circuitBreaker).get(() -> lookup(em, id))));
    }
```

Если бы это был nodejs, то там бы написал такой код с использованием Promise

```
var Q = require('q')

Q.all([ repository.get(id1), repository.get(id2) ])
    .then(result -> {
        console.log(result[0] + ' ' + result[1])
     })
```

Можно ли тоже самое повторить в Java? Мне приходится писать вот такой код:

```
CompletableFuture<CompletionStage<Account>> first = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> repository.get(actionActionTuple._1.getAccountId()));
CompletableFuture<CompletionStage<Account>> second = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> repository.get(actionActionTuple._2.getAccountId()));

return CompletableFuture.allOf(first, second)
        .thenAcceptAsync(res -> {
            System.out.println("res = " + res);
        });
```

На деле получается очень много кода, который имхо не нужен (например, `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> repository.get(actionActionTuple._1.getAccountId()))`)

Comment: Java многословна. Можешь попробовать написать на Scala - будет похоже на твой JavaScript код.

Comment: @EnverOsmanov не могу на Скале сделать, ибо весь проект на Java.

Comment: Технически Scala и Java код совместим. Это как JavaScript и TypeScript в одном проекте. Если не можешь из-за соглашений в команде, то ок.